# How do I test-run my Android Apps on all Android devices

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-testing

I am a  fledgling Android developer and though I can't boast of having publicly released any Android app, the thought of testing-running is disturbing me.

Let's say I developed an app. I tested it on my own physical device and all the emulators in Android Studio (which are all nexus devices anyways); it worked perfectly.

Let's still assume a HTC or Techno or Gionee or Samsung (or another Android hardware manufacturer)  user complains of a bug, how will I debug the app? Do I need to own all Android devices to be able to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Whilst it might not be the best solution for a small developer (and unfortunately the service isn't actually available yet) you should keep you eye on Google's [Butt Test Lab](https://developers.google.com/butt-test-lab/). 
This is automated testing across lots of different physical devices.

Otherwise what I do is upload my APK to the play store as a closed alpha build and add anyone I know with an android phone to it: [Android Aplha/Beta Testing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en-GB)

Comment: Don't know why this comment was downvoted.Alpha/Beta/Internal testing is the next step once you have tested your app yourself.

Answer (score 0):

As a single-developer unit, it can be hard to hit the plethora of devices available that run all kinds of versions of Android.

The best you can hope for is targeting best practices, leveraging pure Android instead of relying too heavily on third party or external libraries.  And, as another answer pointed out, starting a Alpha/Beta testing Google Group to publish and test apps to those you know and trust.

Another way to test devices you don't physically own is checking out Genymotion: https://www.genymotion.com/

You can download images for Android devices and run them in a virtualized environment.  Genymotion also supports a number of (mocked) hardware features, though I suspect you might need a license to use some.

Comment: Is that to say that my apps that's works on my device will work glitchleslly  on all other devices so far I don't use third party libraries ?

Comment: All I'm suggesting is to minimize faults by following best practices and lessen the chance of bugs by including only what you need to include.  You increase risk of failure with every added component, which includes things like 3rd party libraries.  I'm not saying you can't use them, just be aware of their impact.